# Debugging a Windows Service and trying to see what it sees

Tags: windows-services, subprocess

We currently have an automated system that runs as a service for processing satellite images. This service maintains a configuration file, in the configuration file we apply certain scripts(python) to covnert the input satellite imagery into a more usable format. The scripts call the required applications, for the conversion proces.  The scripts themselves are invoked by the service via the system("command") (its written in c/c++). (the service uses the same account as the user).

We currently are trying to add support for another satelitte imagery format, the converter is a commerical .exe from ERDAS Imagine(importavhrr), (we do several of our own steps after in the script to change the projection).

The script works fine, up until it hits this:

```
argslist = ['importavhrr.exe', '-in', '%s' % infn, '-out', '%s' % tmpimg1, '-gui', 'FALSE', '-correct', '-flyingheight', '833', '-rect', 'gcp', gcpfn]
print "".join(argslist)
p = subprocess.Popen(argslist, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print str(p.communicate())
```

What ends up happening now is, importavhrr.exe just sits there, and does nothing(according to taskmanager it sits there using 0 cpu usage, and the memory usage never changes). As if its waiting for some sort of user input. (Trying os.system, os.spawnv both yield same results) I am guessing some sort of gui element is ether popping up with a gui window of sorts. Closing the process from task manager, returns control to python.

Note: The -gui FALSE/false/0 argument is supposed to prevent a gui from poping up. However if the data is bad (i tested this manually by corrupting the data, and invoking via a script) an error window will popup showing the results.

When i run the script manually (same file, same working directory), it works fine.... the script even works when i invoke it manually using the same system function (its part of an inhouse library) as the service.

Also making the service invoke a batch file with just the importavhrr.exe and the enviroment variables also results in the importavhrr.exe hanging.

Service Sidewise:
- Uses the same user account as the one i logged in with
- The python script sets around 30-40 envrioment variables for ERDAS
- All the enviroment variables are properly set(dumping the enviroment variables when the script is first run, and comparing them to what i get when i print the messages)
- Passing the enviroment variables into the subprocess.Popen() yields the same results
- The company refuses to help us because they don't support running programs from command line (however it works fine when a user does it, just not a service)
- Running the service in debug mode works fine.
- I HAVE rebooted the machine.

I am at a loss here, i think (and fear) that the ERDAS executable is making some sort of error message window popup, however i have looked, and looked and can't find any sort of way to see what the service sees. I have been trying to figure this out for almost a week now so yeah.

*EDIT*

I grabbed the recommended Process Explorer, and looking at the stack thread i have this:

```
<snip ntoskrnl calls>
ntdll.dll!KiFastSystemCallRet
ntdll.dll!RtlSetLastWin32ErrorAndNtStatusFromNtStatus+0x301
kernel32.dll!GetModuleHandleA+0xdf
```

After waiting a few minutes, it changes to this:

```
<snip ntoskrnl calls>
ntdll.dll!KiFastSystemCallRet
USER32.dll!ScrollWindowEx+0x121d
USER32.dll!SoftModalMessageBox+0x6f8
USER32.dll!MessageBoxTimeoutW+0x1d9
USER32.dll!MessageBoxTimeoutW+0x5b
USER32.dll!MessageBoxTimeoutA+0x9c
USER32.dll!MessageBoxExA+0x1b
USER32.dll!MessageBoxA+0x45
elib.dll!esmg_GetLocalTapesDB+0x23b
elib.dll!esmg_LogMessageFunc+0x13a
```

Well it is trying to show a window, i presume. I don't know anything about their behaviour to see what could be causing esmg_LogMessageFunc to crash. That function is part of their dev tools, which i have 0 access to. Furthermore i have never actually seen erdas log anything.

Comment: You say that running the service in debug mode works fine. Does that actually mean that a debug build running as a service (i.e. under the SCM, not as a standalone program) doesn't trigger the problem?

Comment: By debug mode i mean using the debug switch for a service. This basically runs the service as a regular exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to use any Windows API calls that assume access to the windowstation will cause problems in the security context of a service.

You can use several of the tools from [Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx) to diagnose this kind of thing. Specifically, consider using [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) in place of Task Manager, and [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) for tracing the activity of a specific process.

**Edit:** Their new [ProcDump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx) tool can be used to get a core dump of any process with really powerful triggering. Several of the latest war stories on [Mark Russinovich's Blog](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963890.aspx) take advantage of ProcDump to discover what really happened.

For completeness, a good overview of "official" tools for debugging a service is at [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/824344).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to allow the service to interact with the desktop, log into the machine and check if an error box is actually popping up?

Comment: +1 Just allowing access to the desktop may be your easiest out, assuming you aren't deploying to a large server farm....

Answer (score 1):

You might want to start with [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx). You can see the threads and the stacks for those thread. If you really think there's an open window you'll likely see this at the bottom of the stack

```
kernel32.dll!RegisterWaitForInputIdle+0x49
```

If that doesn't work out I'd then get a Full Memory Dump of the process and then use WinDBG to see what its doing.