# Debug a Windows Service

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, debugging, windows-services

I have created one windows service which send an email notifications to users (list retrieved from db) every 2 minutes. I wish to check that everything is running ok in web service and hence I wish to debug the service. The service is installed in SMC (services.msc) when an server setup of application is done.

My question: how to debug the windows service?

I **cannot** see the service from

1. Task Manager
2. Attach to process

I have tried from following links

- [Debugging windows services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982636/debugging-windows-services)  (CANNOT understood the FIRST COMMENT- making normal windows form)
- [Debugging a Windows Service and trying to see what it sees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894019/debugging-a-windows-service-and-trying-to-see-what-it-sees)
- [Debug Windows Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629720/debug-windows-service)

I have also given the rights of debugging from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa291232%28VS.71%29.aspx#vxtskdebuggerpermissionsdebuggingasystemservice

Let me know if any input required.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** @maycil

I wrote your `If(!Debug)` code but I guess there is some problem as I don't see proper color of Visual Studio.

[image]

Comment: You can run it as console application then debug that.. as far as I know it's not possible to directly debug code running as Service. http://tech.einaregilsson.com/2007/08/15/run-windows-service-as-a-console-program/

Comment: Have you checked the "Show processes in all sessions" checkbox in the Attach to Process window?

Comment: @Aliostad: Windows XP/ Windows Server 2008

Comment: @jyanrhyn: Yes i have checked the "Show Processes in all sessions"

Comment: @Shadow: http://tech.einaregilsson.com/2007/08/15/run-windows-service-as-a-console-program/ Refer your link and tried first method but CANNOT set the project's output type to Console Application.

Comment: @Romil so what *is* the project type??

Comment: @Shadows: Its a Window Application (WinForms)

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch() is not working?

Comment: @Romil so can't you run the EXE directly and debug it?

Comment: This is yet another dupe question...

Comment: Your question is valid, because developer are usually anxious about it and want to see how each and every line got executed and you already got too many answers, so beside this i would strongly recommend u to use logging e.g. log4net. This would enable you to see how your service is behaving on your production server. Thats a right way to debug a server side application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static void Main()
{
#if (!DEBUG)


            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { new Service1Component() };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);


#else
            Service1Component s = new Service1Component();
            s.StartProcess();
#endif
}
```

try this code in Service1Companent.cs

Comment: thanks for comment. cannot find the StartProcess when writing the code.

Comment: it will be your private code, you can call it in  protected override void OnStart(string[] args) method

Answer (score 2):

Along the lines of maycil's answer you can use Environment.UserInteractive to check if the service is running with a console attached. That way it works as is for both a service and for debugging as a console app.

```
static void Main( string[] args )
{
    if( !Environment.UserInteractive )
    {
        var servicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] {new Service1Component()};
        ServiceBase.Run( servicesToRun );
    }
    else
    {
        var services = new Service1Component();
        services.Start()
        Console.WriteLine( "Press return to exit" );
        Console.ReadLine();
        services.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 I prefer this method over `#if DEBUG` because this works regardless of how the project was built.